# How to use an ordered array in php

Tags: php

I want to extract the website name, from a link, so I write the following function:

```
protected function getWebsiteName()
{
    $prefixs = ['https://', 'http://', 'www.'];

    foreach($prefixs as $prefix)
    {
        if(strpos($this->website_link, $prefix) !== false)
        {
            $len = strlen($prefix);
            $this->website_name = substr($this->website_link, $len);
            $this->website_name = substr($this->website_name, 0, strpos($this->website_name, '.'));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use I website link that look like **https://www.github.com**, the result is: **s://www**, and the function only works when I remove that 'www.' from the array list.

Any ideas why this is happening, or how I can improve this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your code. Each time you go through the `foreach`, **you are applying your logic from the original `website_link` every time**. This means when you run `strlen` in the situation of `www.` after the first two iterations, this happens:

1. `$prefix` is `www.`
2. Therefore, `$len = 4` (the length of `$prefix`)
3. `$this->website_link` is still `https://www.github.com`
4. You apply `substr($this->website_link, 4)`
5. Result is `$this->website_name = 's://www.github.com'`
6. You apply `substr($this->website_name, 0, 7)` (`7` being the result of `strpos($this->website_name, '.')`
7. The result is `$this->website_name = 's://www'`

To fix this, you should save `$this->website_link` to `$temp` and then use the following code:

```
$temp = $this->website_link;
foreach($prefixs as $prefix)
{
    if(strpos($temp, $prefix) !== false)
    {
        $len = strlen($prefix);
        $temp = substr($temp, $len);
    }
}
$this->website_name = substr($temp, 0, strpos($temp, '.'));
```

I'd suggest @dynamic's answer, but if you want to continue the strategy of string replacement, use `str_replace`. It accepts arrays for the needle!

```
$prefixes = ['https://', 'http://', 'www.'];
$this->website_name = str_replace($prefixes, '', $this->website_link);
$this->website_name = substr($this->website_name, 0, strpos($this->website_name, '.'));
```

Comment: in 2, how do you get 4?, i have $len = strlen('https://') wich is the 1st element of $prefixs, so $this->website_name should be the substring from that position to the end, am i getting this wrong ?

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI Because we're dealing with the last iteration. See the edit, I've broken it down further for you.

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI You misunderstand the fundamental problem. **You are applying the logic to the original `$this->website_link` every time,** where you should instead be _compounding_ the `substr` operations to a temporary variable through each iteration. Therefore the first two iterations of `http://` and `https://` do not matter whatsoever because the last iteration is the only thing that remains! If you try the modified code it will work. Even better if you use the last code block that I suggested with `str_replace`, you will be golden.

Comment: yep, exactly, i finaly get it, i forget to update the website link to the new value, thank you sjagr.

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI No problem! If you feel my answer and explanations have helped you best, you can accept my answer by clicking the "checkmark" immediately below the up/down arrows for my answer. You can also accept anyone else's answer in your question if you feel they have helped you better.

Comment: i use your version of str_replace, but when i run my test suite, i get a null value on the website name.

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI Sorry - jumbled my parameters in the `str_replace` function. Try out my edit and tell me if that works.

Comment: the test now is green, thank you, str_replace() clean's up my code a little :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parse_url();`, Try:

```
print_r(parse_url('https//www.name/'));
```

Comment: ok i will try it, but what about the above behavior, why i get that result.

Comment: @sjagr what the you mean? it's exactly doing what i need it to do !!

Comment: from the documentation of parse_url(), i still need to parse the hostname (www.example.com) to extract (example) from it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use parse_url along with preg_match should do the job

```
function getWebsiteName($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is fixing your code.

```
function getWebsiteName()
{
    $this->website_name = $this->website_link;
    $prefixs = array('https://', 'http://', 'www.');

    foreach($prefixs as $prefix)
    {
      if (substr($this->website_name, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        $this->website_name = substr($this->website_name, strlen($prefix));
      }              
    }
}
```